# What is the probablity of January having 5 sundays. Similarly for the other months

Tags: probability, calendar-computations

I'm trying to find out what is the probability that a randomly chosen January will have 5 Sundays. Of course the answer for 4 Sundays would be 1. I presume that 31 day months will have a higher probability of having 5 then 30 day months. Of course, February in a non-leap year has 0 probablity of having 5 sundays and in a leap year will have 5 only if 1st Feb is a Sunday. Therefore in a leap year P(Feb,5) = 1/7 and over a 400 year time period the P(Feb,5) will be 99/2800. I presume all 31 day months will have the same probablity which should be higher than 30 day months and in turn will be higher than 99/2800. I've worked out P(31d month,5) will be 223/343 and P(30d month,5) is 19/49. Is this right?

Comment: Is there a connection between what day the 1st of January is, and how many Sundays there are that January?

Comment: I think it is important to note that number $7$ has [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) 1 both with 355 and 356, so that January the 1st has the same probability of being any of the weekdays.

Comment: Note also that the rules for leap years affect the distribution here - so it depends whether you are talking about a particular century or "the long term". And always assuming the calendar stays the same - it has changed before now.

Comment: @AndreasT In 400 years, there are $146,097 = 20,871\cdot 7$ days with current leap year rules, so some weekdays will be more common than others (I don't know exactly which ones, though, but I remember someone calculating that the 13th will fall on a friday once or twice more than on any other day during that period.

Comment: @Arthur sorry, my bad, Mark Bennet's answer made it clear. I'm still a bit puzzled though :)

Answer (score 7):

You have to be a little careful calculating this. With the leap year rules the calendar repeats after 400 years (the number of days in 400 years is divisible by $7$). In any period of 400 years using the current calendar, 1 January will fall on:

Sunday 58 times

Monday 56 times

Tuesday 58 times

Wednesday 57 times

Thursday 57 times

Friday 58 times

Saturday 56 times

Answer (score 0):

January will have 5 Sundays if January 1 falls on Friday,  Saturday or Sunday. Therefore the probability is 3/7. You can apply the same logic for other months.

Answer (score 0):

now it is sure that the month of jan will have 4 sundays as you said. so 31-28=3 days remaining

the remaining 3 days can have different combination of days

sun-mon-tue

mon-tue-wed

tue-wed-thu

wed-thu-fri

thu-fri-sat

fri-sat-sun

sat-sun-mon

so there are total 7 combinations
and 3 of these combinations contains sunday

so probability of having 5 sundays in the month of january is P(E)= 3/7

Answer (score 0):

3 by 7 is the perfect answer.as there are seven days in a week and there are 3 possible outcomes 
Possible outcomes ÷ total number of favourable outcomes.

Comment: Welcome to this site! The question you just answered is rather old and has perfectly good answers already, to which your post doesn't seem to add much.  More value can be added to the site by answering unanswered questions, or posting answers which significantly add to the existing ones.